# JavaScript prevent infinite loop - possibily with dynamic recognition pattern?

Tags: javascript, recursion, pattern-matching, infinite-loop

first of here is the commented pseudo-code:

```
// TODO:
// Person A (80kg) nutrition intake requirements are:
// nutrient     ||  Unit(g)
// Vitamin A    :   30,
// Vitamin B1   :   2,
// Vitamin C    :   300,
// Vitamin D    :   3000,
// Protein      :   100,
// Calcium      :   30

var nutrient_requirements = {
    vita: {min: 30 ,max: 38},
  vitb1: {min:2, max:4},
  vitc: {min:300, max: 800},
  vitd: {min: 300, max:3000},
  protein: {min:100, max:200},
  calcium: {min:30, max:50}
}

// The calculated estimate amount of food
// the person eats on a daily base is around 900(g)
// The amount will be distributed among the terms
// with a predefined pattern

var food_amount = {
    fruits:[200,200],
  meat: [500]
}

// START (usefull anchor for this pseudocode)

var calculated_nutrition = {
    vita: 0,
  vitb1: 0,
  vitc: 0,
  vitd: 0,
  protein: 0,
  calcium: 0
}

// The daily nutrition intake of this person
// needs to be achieved by the following terms:
// apple, banana, chicken breast
// Term nutrient values per gramm
var terms = {
    fruits:[
    apple:{
        vita: 0.02,
        vitc: 0.30,
        vitd: 0.01,
        protein: 0.08,
        calcium: 0
    },
    banana:{
        vita: 0.1,
        vitc: 0.09,
        vitd: 0.00,
        protein: 0.1,
        calcium: 0.2
    }
  ],
  meat:[
    chicken_breast:{
        vita: 0.07,
        vitc: 0.08,
        vitd: 0.03,
        protein: 0.4,
        calcium: 0.2
    }
  ]
}

// Now we want to see if the normal amount and distribution
// of the food covers the required amount
// To do that we need to multiply the matching food amount
// with the matching food / term and sum up all values

for(let prop in terms){
    for(let i = 0; i < terms[prop].length; i++){
    for(let propb in terms[prop][i]){
        calculated_nutrition[propb] = terms[prop][i][propb] * food_amount[prop][i];
    }
  }
}

// After that is done, we can compare calculated_nutrition to
// nutrient_requirements to see whether something is too much
// or too little

for(let propa in nutrient_requirements){
    if(nutrient_requirements[propa].min > calculated_nutrition[propa]){
    // this nutrient level is too little
    // now we need to increase some food / term
    // in order to achieve the required minimum
    // of this nutrient
    alter_amount(propa, "up");
    return;
  }else if(nutrient_requirements[propa].max < calculated_nutrition[propa]){
    // this nutrient level is too high
    // now we need to decrease some food / term
    // in order to achieve the required minimum
    alter_amount(propa, "down");
    return;
  }else{
    // this nutrient level is ok
    return;
  }
}

function alter_amount(prop, direction){
    // here we look in terms which food
  // has the highest amount of prop

  switch(direction){
    case "down":
        // here we decrease the amount of
      // the matching term in the amount object
            // and re-run this whole calculation from
      // point START
      break;
    case "up":
        // here we increase the amount of
      // the matching term in the amount object
            // and re-run this whole calculation from
      // point START
    break;
  }
}
```

Let me briefly explain this example.

The computed expected result is that, the person needs to eat an X amount of apples, an Y amount of bananas and an Z amount of chicken breast per day to achieve the daily nutrition goal.

In my pseudo code I have written down the basic functionality of my program and the current problem I am facing is, that IF a specific food happens to be the perfect fit for an increase in amount in one loop and then happens to be the perfect fit for a decrease in amount in another loop - I end up in an endless loop.

Based on my minimalistic example I could hardcode that if apple amount got increased, it shouldn't get decreased in the next loop - but in my real world program I am working with a greater ingredient stack with a lot of more properties. So the complexity to cover that up raises extremely.

I am looking for a way to recognize the pattern, that leads to no result and tell the program to pick the 2nd best food for increase or decrease in order to not end in an endless loop.

That something like this gets avoided:

```
apple ++
apple ++
banana ++
apple ++
banana ++
meat --

apple --
apple --
banana --
apple --
banana --
meat ++

apple ++
apple ++
banana ++
apple ++
banana ++
meat --

apple --
apple --
banana --
apple --
banana --
meat ++
...
```

**EDIT**

The answer given below promoting some hashing and storing system leads to the same outcome which I experience with my custom blacklisting method.

My blacklisting method works as following:

Apple amount has been altered (decrement / increment) -> save that to blacklist array.

```
blacklist = [{product: "apple", altered: "down/up"},...]
```

Now every at every loop before choosing the food to increment or decrement the blacklist is scanned. If the perfect fit is in the array, then the second best fit will be chosen and so on.

There are some additional restrictions like: f.e. Apples may not be more than x % of the total amount. Or apples may not be less than x % of the total amount.

**In combination of the restrictions + the blacklisted products my program ends in a state where it has no more different foods to increment or decrement and simply alters nothing and ends in an endless loop without progression**

I don't even know if there is a way to fix that issue programmatically - or if I just have to say "hey, that problem isn't solvable".

All I can think of is a way to implement a functionality, that the program recognizes that it's "stuck" -> remembers the pattern that lead to the stucked state and tries over again with a different approach. But that might be an overkill in thoughts.

Comment: Per stack overflow guidelines, the code you have should be put into the question.  Code required in order to understand the question and/or form an answer MUST be in the question itself.  The amount of code you have in the jsFiddle is not too much code to put directly into the question.  The reason for this is that external links have a habit of disappearing or getting modified, rendering the question less useful as a reference source in the future.

Comment: Thank you I have added the code.

Comment: Please give some sample test case (input and desired output).

Comment: The input is in terms and food_amount, the desired output lies within nutrient_requirements.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a variant of the partition problem to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue. These are some quite interesting methods. But I am not sure if this actually fits my needs. I need something to prevent infinite repetition. When some pattern that doesn't resolve the problem gets chosen over and over again as described in my question :)

Comment: Just my 2 cents: how about comparing the current result with the result from previous run and set a threshold? If improvement is less than threshold, exit loop with current result?

Comment: Here is a wild guess: Try altering the for-loops into array.foreach. Like: var terms = ["apple", "banana", "meat"];
terms.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});

Comment: Each loop represents an increase or decrease of a specific food amount. Every single food has some specific values of nutritions. If we decrease apple to lover VItamin C, we also lower Magnesium and plenty other minerals / vitamins (just an example). So comparing both the current with the last loop and define which is a better fit ... I might be blinded by the current state, but how would I define which is the better choice? In the real world example every loop alters the value by a tiny amount of 0.01 gramms.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to remember the set of all states you visited before and avoid entering a state twice (mark it as a "taboo").

If the state change is small (i.e. if you only mutate a few values) then a useful trick is to use "[zobrist hashing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) so that an hash code for the next state can be computed in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of changes, not the number of variables.

Comment: When would be the "taboo" removed? If I understand your solution correctly I could create an array that contains all objects that have been mutated. If the Object is in the list, avoid it on the next loop etc. If i simply put all mutated objects in the list then there wont be anything left to decrease or increase

Comment: @noa-dev: the idea is to keep an array with **whole solutions** already considered and if the whole solution is there then you don't check it again. To speed up the check if a solution is already in the list of visited ones you can use hashing and zobrist hashing is a technique that can speed up computation of the hash code for small changes.

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide an example based on my usecase? I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: Never mind - I have read through it carefully and came to the conclusion that that is what i am basically doing - just without the hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you are dealing with a classic [`(Unbounded) Knapsack Problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem), of which the aim is to find the best combination of items (food types) to achieve a given measurement (sum of nutritions). Your pseudo-code cannot solve this problem right.

There are various parameters to this problem, which was not mentioned in the question, for example:

- What is the weight of each nutrition?
- Can one nutrition exceeding a little to achieve better results?
- How do you decide which combo is better? (How to reduce a combo to a score?)
- When there are several combos considered equally good, how do you decide which one to go?

You will get less than ideal results if these questions are not answered. When things gone bad, you get stuck in the algorithm.

I wrote a snippet to demonstrate a bruteforce solution to the problem, using my personal thoughts as answers to questions above, with 2 nutritions and 2 food types.

While the problem space get complicated really quickly when adding nutritions/food type, you can always give it various tweaks to make sure it can run within reasonable timeframe on a modern browser.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz902/65f6f2vg/). (You may want to turn off line wrapping.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I will look into it shortly. To answer your question "Which is the weight of each nutrition". In the amount object you find the amount of the food and amount equals to GRAMMS (g).

Comment: And the nutrition requirements object represents the "go-to" values which consist of a minimum value that needs to be achieved and a maximum value that must not be exceeded

Comment: @noa-dev Sorry for the confusion, I should have used "importance" instead of "weight(ing)". When creating combinations, items may have different importance. When you put things into a bag, you may aim for "highest value" or "largest quantity". Different combo may be seen as "better" depending on this setting. I've used equal importance in the demo, and you can change that (along with the range you have given) to tweak the algorithm.

Comment: Ah I see. The importance of a food is based on the current requirement. If Vitamin C is missing then the Food with the highest Vitamin C value per gramm has the highest importance and gets increased in the loop. Unfortunately I can't simply divide the current amount through the requirement and receive a % match since I have a min and max value in which the result must be.

Comment: Take a look at the demo, the parameters can be configured easily to match your needs. I used descriptive variable names and comments for easy adoption.

Comment: Yea I saw that. Thank you for your effort:). I will need to wait to try it out on my real example.